# C stack with ADT - Abstract data type

Tags: c, types, stack, abstract

If i have this stack abstract type that i've to use :

stack.h:

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

typedef enum { STACK_OK, STACK_EMPTY, STACK_FULL } StackStatut;

void pushToStack(void * x);
void * popFromStack(void);
unsigned countStack(void);

#endif
```

stack.c:

```
#include "stack.h"
#define MAX_ELEMS 200
static unsigned numbElems = 0;
static void * elems[MAX_ELEMS];

void pushToStack(void * x) {
    elems[numbElems++] = x;
}

void * popFromStack(void) {
    return elems[--numbElems];
}

unsigned countStack(void){
    return numbElems;
}
```

When i come in my main.c, i know that i've to include stack.h in order to be able to declare a pointer to build a stack.

The point is that i've NO clue how to proceed. I know how to deal with ADT when it's come to a struct but now i'm completly lost.

if i 've let say :
main.c:

```
 #include "stack.h"
    int main() {
       int i = 1;
       int j = 2;
       int k ; 3;

       // At this point, i know that i need a void * prt
       int * prt;

       // This is the part where i dont know how to start my stack.
       // if i do :
       pushToStack(&i);

       // i dont know how the number of elem in the stack will be incremented
       // I dont know neither how to apply a statut to the stack.

    }
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: And i can't change the header and source files. We can't do it.

Comment: You don't need to start anything. You just need to called pushToStack() and popFromStack() and countStack(). Everything should be initialized

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's worked very well , but i still dont quite understand how the program works, how i get 0 it a call countStack, where do he take that number !

But thanks a lot seriously !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stack is intialized in the stack.c

```
static unsigned numbElems = 0;
static void * elems[MAX_ELEMS];
```

These two lines create your stack and set the current count to 0